# How to remove netting values (zero values by balance) Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to solve this problem in Oracle SQL, I have this table:

| balance | account | subaccount | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 251 | 23000 | 230014 | **-1000** |
| 251 | 23001 | 230013 | **1000** |
| 251 | 23002 | 230012 | -1000 |
| 250 | 22000 | 220014 | 1000 |
| 250 | 22001 | 220013 | -500 |
| 250 | 22002 | 220012 | -500 |
| 250 | 22011 | 220011 | **-200** |
| 250 | 22012 | 220010 | **200** |

And in the end I want to have only this:

| balance | account | subaccount | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 251 | 23002 | 230012 | -1000 |
| 250 | 22000 | 220014 | 1000 |
| 250 | 22001 | 220013 | -500 |
| 250 | 22002 | 220012 | -500 |

I want to remove the netting values by balance, with the same amount and not with the sum(amount).

Can you please help me?

Thanks,

Comment: How are the first two lines referring to the same account? We have account of 23000 and 23001, respectively and subaccount of 230014 and 230013, respectively. How are these two records representing the same account?

Comment: Don't assume that anyone reading your question is in context: this is not true, especially for technical site. Please describe the terminology and rules you use: what do *netting values* and *not with the sum(amount)* mean? Also please post your current code and describe what is the issue with it

Comment: @astentx as far as I understand, the question is all about showing only the not-retracted payments by account. So, if you pay 1000 and then pay -1000, then you have a net zero. The issue that prevents me from answering this question currently is that currently I do not - yet - understand how are the first two (and last two) records in the example table related to the same account. There is a further problem, like how should we handle a payment of 100 vs. a payment of -59. I suppose we need to sum the payments of each account and filter out those that have a 0 sum.

Comment: @LajosArpad This is the reason why I wrote my comment: we can provide some SQL code that returns expected result set but there's no any way to verify it: there's no deterministic rules of calculation, there's no another sample to provide as input and test model's output for it, there's no any info about edge cases etc. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/2778710)

Comment: @astentx I would be confident about writing an answer if my comment was answered. An answer can delve into separate cases and explain how the query changes. But we need solid understanding about what's connecting the records to be able to properly group.

Comment: The question, terminology and naming are all confusing. The title says "netting values (zero values by account)", the body says "netting values by balance", and the example does seem to be by balance. Having 'balance' as an identifier just seems odd (vs something like an account number), and you haven't said how you decide which rows to combine to 'net' and which you keep - why does 251 keep 23002 and not 23000? Can there be other values between -/+1000? It seems like you've attempted to come up with a modified/simplified version of your real issue, but in doing so have made it unclear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use analytic functions to index the rows for each `balance`/`value` combination and then to count when you have pairs of rows with the same `balance`/absolute `value`/index and exclude those rows:

```sql
SELECT balance, account, subaccount, value
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY balance, ABS(value), rn) AS cnt
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY balance, value
             ORDER BY ROWNUM
           ) AS rn
    FROM   table_name t
  ) t
)
WHERE  cnt = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (balance, account, subaccount, value) AS
SELECT 251, 23000, 230014, -1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 251, 23001, 230013,  1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 251, 23002, 230012, -1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 250, 22000, 220014,  1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 250, 22001, 220013,  -500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 250, 22002, 220012,  -500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 250, 22011, 220011,  -200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 250, 22012, 220010,   200 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| BALANCE | ACCOUNT | SUBACCOUNT | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 250 | 22001 | 220013 | -500 |
| 250 | 22002 | 220012 | -500 |
| 250 | 22000 | 220014 | 1000 |
| 251 | 23002 | 230012 | -1000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FkOiDsVl)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
with data(balance, account, subaccount, value) as (
    select 251, 23000, 230014, -1000 from dual union all
    select 251, 23001, 230013, 1000 from dual union all
    select 251, 23002, 230012, -1000 from dual union all
    select 250, 22000, 220014, 1000 from dual union all
    select 250, 22001, 220013, -500 from dual union all
    select 250, 22002, 220012, -500 from dual union all
    select 250, 22011, 220011, -200 from dual union all
    select 250, 22012, 220010, 200 from dual -- union all
),
rdata(balance, account, subaccount, value, rn) as (
    select 
        balance, account, subaccount, value,
        row_number() over(partition by balance order by account) as rn
    from data
),
ldata(balance, account, subaccount, value, rn, rnl) as (
    select d1.balance, d1.account, d1.subaccount, d1.value, d1.rn, d2.rn as rnl
    from rdata d1
    join rdata d2
        on d1.balance = d2.balance and d1.rn < d2.rn and d1.value = -d2.value
)
select balance, account, subaccount, value from rdata d
where not exists(
    select 1 from ldata d1
    where not exists(
        select 1 from ldata d2 where d1.balance = d2.balance
            and d1.rn = d2.rnl
    )
    and d.balance = d1.balance and (d.rn = d1.rn or d.rn = d1.rnl)
)
order by d.balance, d.rn
;


250 22000   220014  1000
250 22001   220013  -500
250 22002   220012  -500
251 23002   230012  -1000
```